# conditions such that every integer satisfies at least one of the congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am kind of stuck in this problem. I have a solution but not confident about it. Here's the question

Find all integers $a_1,\cdots,a_5$ such that every integer $x$ satisfies at least one of the congruences
$x \equiv a_1\pmod{2},x \equiv a_2\pmod{3},x \equiv a_3\pmod{4},x \equiv a_4\pmod{6},x \equiv a_5\pmod{12}$

My approach to this problem is as follows:

Now any integer $x$ belongs to one of the equivalence classes of $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ that is $x$ is of the form $12k+r$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ & $r \in \{0,1,2,3, \cdots, 11\}$

Claim : $a_1 = 2s $ so all numbers of the form $12k + 2r$ satisfy $x \equiv a_1\pmod{2}$ where $r \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,5\}$

Now for the remaining classes wrt modulo $12$ we consider $a_3$ of the form $4m$ so for integers of the form $12k,12k+4, 12k+8$ we have one congruence namely $x \equiv a_3\pmod{4}$ satisfying them. Now we are left with $3$ classes wrt modulo $12$ for $a_2, a_4, a_5$. Take $a_2 = 12p + 2, a_4 = 12q + 6$ and $a_5 = 12l +10$

I think this does solve the problem. One such set of $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)$ is $(1,2,4,6,10)$ and it does work.

Comment: I didn't read your entire argument, but did you check your solution?  $x=16$ doesn't work

Comment: Are there any solutions?  Just loosely:  there are $12$ residues $\pmod {12}$.  Half will be covered by the parity, $a_1$ which leaves six.  Now, $a_2$ will cover $4$ residues but two of those will have the same parity as $a_1$, so you only get $2$ new residues $\pmod {12}$.  Similarly, $a_4$ gives you one new one, and $a_5$ of course just gives you one new one.  $a_3$ is irrelevant, as $5$ is prime to $12$.

Comment: @lulu ah that was typo, that's supposed to be 4 instead of 5.

Comment: Correction:  $a_4$ can get you two new ones (as $6$ is even), but it's not enough.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yeah you are right, it was a typo from my side, it's $a_3 \equiv 3\pmod{4}$ not $5$

Comment: Post edit:  You get $6$ residues $\pmod {12}$ from $a_1$, $2$ from $a_2$, $3$ from $a_3$, $2$ from $a_4$ and $1$ from $a_5$.  And, happily, $6+2+3+2+1>12$ so now there will be solutions.

Comment: @CalvinLin  Still too few, for the original problem. but post edit it works out.

Comment: (@lulu Ah, I read post edit, hence my modulo)

Comment: In fact, a slight modification of lulu's idea tells us that 1/ We have $6+4+3+2+1 = 16$ values, so can have at most 4 overlap. 2/ We almost certainly need $a_1, a_3$ to give us distinct coverage. First show this. Then show that under this case, we have exactly 4 overlaps.